# IIS 6.0 W3C Log Folder

Tags: iis, logging, iis-6, iis-manager

In IIS 6.0 Manager when setting the logging properties for a web site I have selected W3C Extended Log File Format. I have selected a log file directory but would also like to be able to change the name of log folder which is auto-generated(i.e. W3SVCXXXXXXXX\exyymmdd.log).

Is it possible to change the name of the W3SVC folder? If so how?

Update:

After further research I discovered that the folder name will be W3SVC#. The # refers to the instance of that site and is also known as the identifier. The Default Web Site will always be 1 and every other site will have a random number assigned to it.

If this is true then there would be no way to choose the name of this folder. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Answer: The randomly generated number is also the website identifier which is customizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The randomly generated number is also the website identifier which can be customized.